# Combining several regression tables into one for use in xtable with Sweave in R

Tags: r, sweave, xtable

`xtable` in `Sweave` works awesome, but does one table per regression. You can feed it a data frame, too, so I have been manually `rbind`ing and `paste`ing results into data frames, but that doesn't seem very scalable.

Is there a more automated/robust solution that works like `xtable`, but on multiple `lm` objects? Are all of the tables that I see in papers/books generated manually? Is there a better solution to my janky code that generates a data frame to feed to `xtable`?

```
    library(reshape2)

    data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50), 10, 5))
    names(data) <- letters[1:5]
    l.raw <- list()
    l.raw[["a"]] <- lm(a ~ d + e, data=data)
    l.raw[["b"]] <- lm(b ~ d + e, data=data)
    l.raw[["c"]] <- lm(c ~ d + e, data=data)

    form.table.from.lm <- function(l.raw) {
    summ <- list()

    for (i in names(l.raw)) {
        temp <- coef(summary(l.raw[[i]]))
        summ[[i]] <- data.frame(param=rownames(temp), test=i, temp)
    }

    df.res <- do.call("rbind", summ)
    df.res <- transform(df.res, t.value = paste("(", signif(t.value), ")", sep=""), Estimate = signif(Estimate))
    df.res.long <- melt(df.res, id.vars=c("test", "param"))
    df.res.wide <- dcast(df.res.long, test + variable ~ param)

    temp <- subset(df.res.wide, variable %in% c("Estimate", "t.value"))
    df.res <- temp[, -2]
    df.res[, 1] <- as.vector(rbind(names(l.raw), ""))
    colnames(df.res)[1] <- "regressor"
    return(df.res)
}
```

Which produces data frame:

```
   regressor (Intercept)          d          e
1          a    0.393996  -0.666721   0.159508
2             (0.573926) (0.422125) (0.526446)
5          b    0.611077  0.0288942   -0.70033
6              (0.32696)  (0.24048) (0.299911)
9          c   -0.101033  -0.287821    0.14581
10            (0.203193) (0.149449) (0.186383)
```

Given the amazing plotting packages for R, I feel like google and rseek are hiding something from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A while ago I stumbled across the `outreg` function by Paul Johnson.

You can directly apply `outreg` to your `lm` object and combine several
`lm` outputs into one, nice latex table.

Here you find an example .pdf

[outreg examples](http://pj.freefaculty.org/R/outreg-worked2.pdf)

and the code for the function

[outreg code](http://pj.freefaculty.org/R/outreg-worked.R)

general homepage by Paul Johnson

[Paul Johnson](http://pj.freefaculty.org/cgi-bin/twiki/view.pl)

Comment: Thanks! That should cover a lot of the cases I come across.

Comment: For people who see this now (much later)... it looks like Paul Johnson has now combined some of his many R snippets (including outreg) into a package called "rockchalk." Documentation: http://pj.freefaculty.org/R/rockchalk.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Your code threw errors for me at the dcast call, so I simply read in the output that you offered and adjusted the colnames to match up. This code produces a well formed pdf file on my system after passing it through my LaTex processor. (I assume you have an appropriate LaTeX installation if you are already using Sweave.)

```
require(Hmisc)
latex(df.res)
```

When I passed the example in help(lmList) in the  lme4 package latex() also produce a fairly large and unweildy 4 page display that would need some adjustments to widen the page on my machine but may also be worth examination.

```
require(lme4)
(fm1 <- lmList(Reaction ~ Days | Subject, sleepstudy))
latex(fm1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `lmList`. That will really come in handy. I'll re-paste the code above. It works for me, but it looks like Paul Johnson has code with some of the functionality I'm seeking (MRopa's answer).

Comment: Glad you found so use for it. Checking out these options advanced my knowledge in this area too so I guess I ought to vote up the question, eh?

Answer (score 1):

The outreg link in the accepted answer is broken now.  The new link is

http://pj.freefaculty.org/stat/ps706/outreg-worked.R

There is also an accompanying PDF in the parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [apsrtable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apsrtable/index.html) table package in CRAN Which creates American Political Science Review style tables which look roughly like what I think you want. It takes lm and glm models as well some non-linear models from some packages. It also has a long series of options for generating stars at particular levels and such. There's [a nice vingette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apsrtable/vignettes/guide.pdf) and it generates both LaTeX and HTML tables which can then be added to OpenOffice/Word.

I've been using it for 2-3 years now and it continues to be under active development. I've just looked quickly but it seems much more solid/featureful than outreg.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more options I saw go by [CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/) that reminded me of this question:

[texreg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/index.html) — Looking at the [vingette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/texreg.pd), it seems to do a really nice job of generating pretty standard regression tables in R and which is under very active development at time of writing.

**Update:** I've been playing around with a few of these and I think that over time, *texreg* has become the leader leader in this space in terms of it maturity, stability, and featurefulness. Most important to me, it works with a variety of models and does wonderfully handy things like bootstrap standard errors to build stars for `lme4()` models — something that the package itself makes a little tricky to get (for good reasons) but that reviewers and journals often demand nonetheless. I would strongly recommend using texreg. It seems to be actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The package [stargazer](https://cran.r-project.org/package=stargazer) would be another option for HTML, LaTeX, or ASCII tables, side-by-side. See also my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51673007/2563804) to [Table of multiple lm() models using apsrtable in Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44278665/2563804) that includes a screenshot.