# Table of multiple lm() models using apsrtable in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, lm, sweave

## Goal

Present the results of multiple models, created using the `lm()` function, together in a nicely-formatted table. This table will be generated in a .Rmd file and output to a PDF document.

## Proposed Solution

In *Reproducible Research with R and RStudio*, there is an example using the `apsrtable()` function to display multiple models side-by-side. This book provides the following code (p. 173-174):

**Code**

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{Example Nested Estimates Table with \emph{aprstable}}
    \label{BasicApsrTableExample}
        \begin{center}
<<results= asis , echo=FALSE>>=
# Load apsrtable package
library(apsrtable)
# Create nested regression model table
apsrtable(M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, Sweave = TRUE,
      stars = "default")
@
       \end{center}
\end{table}
```

where the models `M1 ... M5` are created in chunks using `M2 <- lm(Examination ~ Education + Agriculture, data = swiss)`.

**Output**

Below is a screen grab of the results, as reported in the book. This is exactly the table I want to create in my .Rmd file and output to a PDF document.

[image]

## Issues

**Attempt 1**
When I try to use this code *inside* a code chunk—as shown below—and the output to a PDF, I get a an error message: `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

````
```{r}
t.model2 = xtable(model2,label = NULL)
t.model3 = xtable(model3,label = NULL)

library(apsrtable)

apsrtable(t.model2, t.model3, Sweave = TRUE, stars = "default")
```
````

**Attempt 2**
When I use the above code *outside* a code chunk, the .Rmd file outputs to PDF, but displays the following:

[image]

## Questions

**My Questions**

- Why are these attempts failing?
- What is the correct way to use the
  `apsrtable` function inside a .Rmd?
- Will this method work to ouput this .Rmd file to PDF?

**Related Stack Overflow Questions**

- [Tools for making latex tables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465314/tools-for-making-latex-tables-in-r/5465429#5465429)
- [Include apsrtable (or stargazer) output in an Rmd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797440/include-apsrtable-or-stargazer-output-in-an-rmd-file)
- [Combining several regression tables into one for use in xtable with Sweave in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347634/combining-several-regression-tables-into-one-for-use-in-xtable-with-sweave-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of the following two things:

- Chunk option `results='asis'`
- `\usepackage{dcolumn}` must be in the preamble as stated in the help file.

Another option would be the [stargazer](https://cran.r-project.org/package=stargazer) package, which allows to knit not only to PDF but to HTML as well (see screenshot).

````
---
title: "stargazer"
author: "hplieninger"
date: "3 August 2018"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{dcolumn}
---

```{r}
m1 <- lm(Fertility ~ Education , data = swiss)
m2 <- lm(Fertility ~ Education + Agriculture, data = swiss)
m3 <- lm(Fertility ~ . , data = swiss)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
apsrtable::apsrtable(m1, m2, m3, Sweave = TRUE)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
# If output: pdf_document
stargazer::stargazer(m1, m2, m3)
# If output: html_document
# stargazer::stargazer(m1, m2, m3, type = "html")
```
````

[image: multiple lm() regression models using stargazer in Rmarkdown]